# Can't find valid lib when building Google Chrome NaCl application .nexe file

Tags: linux, google-chrome-extension, makefile, google-nativeclient, libtomcrypt

## Problem - Can't build .nexe with `libtomcrypt` (`-ltomcrypt`) on 64bit machine

"skipping incompatible" or "not found".

```
/home/ME/nacl/pepper_35/toolchain/linux_x86_newlib/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-nacl/4.4.3/../../../../x86_64-nacl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/ME/nacl/pepper_35/toolchain/linux_x86_newlib/i686-nacl/usr/lib/libtomcrypt.a when searching for -ltomcrypt
/home/ME/nacl/pepper_35/toolchain/linux_x86_newlib/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-nacl/4.4.3/../../../../x86_64-nacl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/ME/nacl/pepper_35/toolchain/linux_x86_newlib/bin/../x86_64-nacl/usr/lib/libtomcrypt.a when searching for -ltomcrypt
/home/ME/nacl/pepper_35/toolchain/linux_x86_newlib/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-nacl/4.4.3/../../../../x86_64-nacl/bin/ld: cannot find -ltomcrypt

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [newlib/Release/my_module_unstripped_x86_32.nexe] Error 1
```

## Makefile

Copy of existing example in downloaded nacl sdk. Modified with `tomcrypt` which result in `-ltomcrypt` flag.

```
VALID_TOOLCHAINS := newlib glibc pnacl linux

NACL_SDK_ROOT ?= $(abspath $(CURDIR)/../..)

include $(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/tools/common.mk


TARGET = my_module
LIBS = ppapi_cpp ppapi pthread tomcrypt

CFLAGS = -Wall
SOURCES = my_module.cc

# Build rules generated by macros from common.mk:

$(foreach src,$(SOURCES),$(eval $(call COMPILE_RULE,$(src),$(CFLAGS))))

ifeq ($(CONFIG),Release)
$(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET)_unstripped,$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
$(eval $(call STRIP_RULE,$(TARGET),$(TARGET)_unstripped))
else
$(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET),$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
endif

$(eval $(call NMF_RULE,$(TARGET),))
```

## What I have

- Linux 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- `my_module.cc` - nacl module code (no more .cc files)

  - `#include <tomcrypt.h>`
- `Makefile` (above)
- `~/nacl/pepper_35/`
- `~/nacl/naclports`

I tried to reinstall `libtocrypt` with naclports, but no progress. 
As I understant my `tomcrypt` lib built as 32bit but I don't know how to point compiler to make it 64bit.

There is no errors if Makefile is without `tomcrypt` flag.

I'm not Makefile or C++ pro, but I'm digging there slowly, so it's best to give instructions for me as for newbie on this topics :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been actually a different issue. (I understan dit right after I posted question.. And only now was able to test it).

**Actually I was able to make 64bit .nexe**. Problem was with 32bit .nexe. It failed that i couldn't compile them. Error message "skipping incompatible" was given that i tried to find 32bit file but it was 64bit.
When I understand that I found similar [issue and solution hint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85978/building-a-32-bit-app-in-64-bit-ubuntu).

### Go back to naclports and remove installed libs.

```
$ cd naclports/src
$ ./make_all.sh clean
```

### Edit `make_all.sh` to compile naclports libs with `-m32` flags

**First** install `g++-multilib` to be able to compile 32bit apps.
I have ubuntu, so

```
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```

Next define flag variables and move `# i686 NaCl` section to end (so given flags don't break another 64bit sections)

```
...
export CFLAGS
export CXXFLAGS
export LDFLAGS

...     
# i686 NaCl
NACL_ARCH=i686
TOOLCHAIN=glibc
CFLAGS="-m32"
CXXFLAGS="-m32"
LDFLAGS="-m32"
make ${TARGETS}
TOOLCHAIN=newlib
make ${TARGETS}
```

### Make your libs again

```
./make_all.sh libtomcrypt
```

### Finally make your NaCl module

Using same Makefile that I copied in question.

```
$ cd my_module/
$ make
  CXX  newlib/Release/my_module_x86_32.o
  LINK newlib/Release/my_module_unstripped_x86_32.nexe
  VALIDATE newlib/Release/my_module_unstripped_x86_32.nexe
  CXX  newlib/Release/my_module_x86_64.o
  LINK newlib/Release/my_module_unstripped_x86_64.nexe
  VALIDATE newlib/Release/my_module_unstripped_x86_64.nexe
  CXX  newlib/Release/my_module_arm.o
  LINK newlib/Release/my_module_unstripped_arm.nexe
  VALIDATE newlib/Release/my_module_unstripped_arm.nexe
  STRIP newlib/Release/my_module_x86_32.nexe
  STRIP newlib/Release/my_module_x86_64.nexe
  STRIP newlib/Release/my_module_arm.nexe
  CREATE_NMF newlib/Release/my_module.nmf
```

Success!